# Saving text input to device

Tags: swift

I am trying to make a view where I can input text in a UITextField and save it to the device. I have searched different places and so far I got this below but I cannot get past this error. Can someone please help?

> Use of unresolved identifier 'yyyytoss'

```
import UIKit

class WritestoryVC: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var myStory : UITextView!

    @IBAction func saveImageToDocumentDirectory(_ chosenImage: UITextField) -> Void {
        let directoryPath =  NSHomeDirectory().appending("/Documents/")
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: directoryPath) {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: NSURL.fileURL(withPath: directoryPath), withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        let filename = NSDate().string(withDateFormatter: yyyytoss).appending(".rtf")
        let filepath = directoryPath.appending(filename)
        let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: filepath)
        do {
            try UITextField(chosenImage, 1.0)?.write(to: url, options: .atomic)
            return String.init("/Documents/\(filename)")

        } catch {
            print(error)
            print("file cant not be save at path \(filepath), with error : \(error)");
            return filepath
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `yyyytoss` in `NSDate().string(withDateFormatter: yyyytoss).appending(".rtf")` line? Have you declared it anywhere? And not getting `UITextField(chosenImage, 1.0)` ? Are you using any third party library? Also your question title doesn't match with your code.

Comment: 1. Do not use `NSHomeDirectory()` in iOS. There are proper ways to get a reference to the app's Documents folder. 2. Do not use `NSDate` in Swift, use `Date`. Do not use `NSURL`, use `URL`. 3. Most of your path building code is wrong.

Comment: If this is the dateformat you want then try `yyyytoss` in double quotes `"yyyytoss"` as this is a format and expects string value.

Comment: @TheTiger `"yyyytoss"` is not a valid date format.

Comment: ... and creating `Documents` in the home folder is redundant. Don't do that. It's one of the standard folders. Please read the error message. It's pretty clear. Where is `yyyytoss` declared?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes but I assume it will give like `"2018to59"`. Although its very unclear what he wants to do :)

Comment: @rmaddy Just tried this is giving year only.

Comment: @TheTiger Which is why I said it wasn't valid. If the "to" is literal text it needs to be quoted: `"yyyy'to'ss"`. But having the year, then the word "to" followed by the seconds makes no sense at all.

Comment: sorry if its not clear, I have been searching for a way to create and save a rtf textfile via viewcontroller that uses uitextfield and create story button.... but seems like this code is outdated

Answer (score 0):

See if it helps:-

Also where you define yyyytoss constant, it should be like "yyyy-MM-dd"

```
let file = "file.txt" //this is the file. we will write to and read from it

let text = "some text" //just a text

if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)

//writing
do {
    try text.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
}
catch {/* error handling here */}

//reading
do {
    let text2 = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)
}
catch {/* error handling here */}
}
```